# How to merge two rows and get single array in Codeigniter/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

I am working on Codeigniter for assigning multiple roles to the single user. For that I have created a table with following values.

```
    Array
(
    [Id] => 1
    [Store_address_id] => 
    [Customer_ref_id] => 193
    [Role_ref_id] => 1
    [Email_alert] => 0
    [Sms_alert] => 0
    [Admin_view] => 0
    [Admin_save] => 0
    [Admin_delete] => 0
    [Master_view] => 1
    [Master_save] => 1
    [Master_delete] => 1
    [Business_view] => 0
    [Business_save] => 0
    [Business_delete] => 0
    [Analytics_view] => 1
    [Analytics_delete] => 1
    [Analytics_save] => 1
    [Promotion_view] => 1
    [Promotion_save] => 1
    [Promotion_delete] => 1
)
```

But, in database I am having multiple rows for that I need to get the value with the validation like this

```
+----+----+----+
| i/p|i/p | o/p|
+----+----+----+
| 0  | 0  | 0  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 1  | 1  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 0  | 1  |
+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 1  |
+----+----+----+
```

My table is like this

[image: MySqlTable]

I need to validate and fetch as a single array.

Comment: I am confused. Are you saying customer_ref_id 193 can both view and not view the business_view?

Comment: Here I'm getting all the values with the `customer_ref_id` as primary value for fetching the values, there will be `n` number of values in the `customer_ref_id` I need to get all the rows which contain 193. So, I need to validate all the columns. I either one of all rows contain i have to get output as 1. Is it possible?

Comment: To me it seems like your database design needs some work. However given where you are now it might be easiest to simply collect all the relevant rows and then run through them in a loop creating a permissions array of some sort. You could try using select_max to get the maximum values out but given so many columns this would be a very long winded way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment thought I would suggest something like this to do it in your controller:

```
// set a permissions array and set to default values of 0
$permissions =  array(
    'Email_alert' => 0,
    'Sms_alert' => 0,
    'Admin_view' => 0,
    'Admin_save' => 0,
    'Admin_delete' => 0,
    'Master_view' => 0,
    'Master_save' => 0,
    'Master_delete' => 0,
    'Business_view' => 0,
    'Business_save' => 0,
    'Business_delete' => 0,
    'Analytics_view' => 0,
    'Analytics_delete' => 0,
    'Analytics_save' => 0,
    'Promotion_view' => 0,
    'Promotion_save' => 0,
    'Promotion_delete' => 0,
);

// get the rows
foreach ($results as $row) {
    // get each col name and value
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        // make sure it is a value needed for the permissions array
        if(isset($permissions[$key])) {
            // this value is a permissions value, is it a 1
            if ($value == 1) {
                // set the permissions array to 1
                $permissions[$key] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just me typing it out, so have not tested it and there may be some typo's. Hope it helps. There may be more efficient ways to do this but if you are only dealing with a few rows this would be fine.